# Metric Space where every real continuous functions are Bounded, but does not attain its Bound.

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

Are there any metric space in which every continuous function are bounded but there exists one such function who does not attain its bound.

Comment: Barring a few pieces of relevant information, the short answer is no, because a constant function is continuous.

Comment: I think I could not explain my question. I have edited it. Please have a look. please Let me know if I am thinking wrong.

Comment: "Bounded" just means some bound exists, so there is no such thing as "the" bound of a function.

Comment: I thought about this question because X is compact <=> every real continuous function from X is bounded and attains its bounds.
So if the condition "attains its bounds" is removed, does the left implication still hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about real-valued functions, there is not. A space on which every continuous real-valued function is bounded is called [*pseudocompact*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space), and every pseudocompact metric space is compact. Finally, every real-valued function on a compact space attains its maximum and minimum values.

Comment: Thank you, Is this true that every type of compactness in metric spaces is equivalent?

Comment: @SaikatGoswami: Certainly all of the usual ones are: countable compactness, sequential compactness, limit point compactness, and pseudocompactness.